# Compare two cols of one file with another file of same cols and fetch the matches_large dataset_14GB

Tags: pandas, bioinformatics, genome

I have file1 of 650,000 rows with two cols, "Chr" and "Pos". I want to compare this file with dbsnp (file2) datadump and match with with Chr and Pos col present in dbSNP dump. Once matched, respective rsid's to be fetched. I tried using Python Panda's but my process is getting killed. When it tried for 50000 rows it worked.

How can I fetch rsid for whole dataset (file1 = 650k rows) from dbSNP (file2)

```
#Program to compare Chr and Pos of a sample with dBSNP and fetching RSIDs
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("v2_infi_chr_pos.csv",sep='\t',dtype='unicode')
df2 = pd.read_csv("dbsnp150_header.txt",sep='\t',dtype='unicode')
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Chr''Pos', how='inner')
export_csv = df3.to_csv (r'rsids_infiniumv2_hg38.txt', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Your syntax for pd.merge is wrong

Comment: Yes, I have passed two parameters in condition. Is there any alternative for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Mohit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965571/compare-two-cols-of-one-file-with-another-file-of-same-cols-and-fetch-the-matche#comment98582611_55965571) and reading through the Pandas 0.24.2 [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) documentation, here is how I would go about it -

```
# Program to compare Chr and Pos of a sample with dBSNP and fetching RSIDs

# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# read in data files
df1 = pd.read_csv("v2_infi_chr_pos.csv",sep='\t',dtype='unicode')
df2 = pd.read_csv("dbsnp150_header.txt",sep='\t',dtype='unicode')

# merge on matched columns 
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['Chr', 'Pos'], how='inner')

# export merged df to file
export_csv = df3.to_csv (r'rsids_infiniumv2_hg38.txt', index = None, header=True)
```

The `on` parameter in `df.merge()` takes in a single label or multiple labels as a list. Since you want to match on multiple columns, supplying a list of column names would work.

Also, how is your process getting killed? Posting your error message would be more helpful.

Comment: I really appreciate the error that you helped me to find out, present in my script. After re-running the script, last message print on screen is, "Killed". FYI: dbsnp150_header file is 14GB containing 358875864 rows and v2_infi contain 1L rows. Env. setup is 16GB ram and 6 cores.